# What is the purpose of signing and validating mechanism in JWT?

Tags: security, jwt

Correct me if I am wrong. JWT based auth works this way: server receives request with JWT token from client and then validate it using some other token (secret key, Azure public key, etc.), in the end the JWT is either validated or not and this is how we validate user. But what is the purpose of this signed token and validating it? If I somehow will steal this JWT and send it with request to server - will it still successfully validate me? If yes then what is the difference between simple token (not signed that you don't validate) and JWT?

Comment: It's not about _stealing_ the token necessarily. What if you had a legitimate token but edited the payload to change your role or permissions? Without a signature, how would the server know?

Comment: @jonrsharpe so it is about some cases when you are authorizing using some trird party service that is providing your data? that makes sense, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the use case that you describe there is no difference between a simple token and a JWT when it comes to assurance about the *presenting* party, since the JWT is used as a so-called bearer token. However:

1. the signature on the JWT allows the receiver to identify and verify the *issuer* of the jWT, which makes it possible to discriminate between different token issuing parties and their associated trust levels
2. a JWT contains verifiable information in a structured format that is easy to parse for receivers. This information can be used for - possibly delegated - access control purposes, which makes JWTs more versatile than simple tokens.
3. a JWT *may* also contain information that identifies and the presenter in a verifiable way (Proof-of-Possession, an extension under development), which would be an improvement over bearer tokens